# android studio open emoji keyboard from default keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, chat, emoji

When I use `android:inputType="textShortMessage"` it'll display emoji symbol in my keyboard [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGe7m.png) and it opens a list of emojis. 
That helps me a lot - but the problem is I want to display the list of image by clicking an imageview in the keyboard.

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ramaraju use this library to app gradle

```
compile 'hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library:supernova-emoji-library:0.0.2'
```

In Oncreate place

```
ImageView Emoji = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.emoji);
EmojiconEditText emojiconEditText = (EmojiconEditText) findViewById(R.id.emojicon_edit_text);
EmojIconActions emojIcon = new EmojIconActions(this, main, emojiconEditText, Emoji);


emojIcon.setKeyboardListener(new EmojIconActions.KeyboardListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyboardOpen() {

            }
            @Override
            public void onKeyboardClose() {
            }
        });
```

Comment: this is working fine for me but i don't want to use any third party libraries because after API 21 google keyboard uses some builtin emojies and those will come to use by only adding android:inputType="textShortMessage" to our edittext in xml...... i want to open those emojies directly from passing any key event from image click listner............ hope its not possible upto now.......... any way thanks for answer

Comment: @Ramaraju did you got any solution other than third party library?

Comment: @Rajasekher can you provide a classpath for the same? I am getting error "Cannot access class 'Helper.EmojiconEditText'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies" by using this