# How to open native emoji keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, emoji

IOS and Android have their own emoji keyboards which can be accessed through their keyboards. How can I directly open it when the user tapped the button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open emoji keyboard in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58351049/how-to-open-emoji-keyboard-in-flutter)

Comment: @Akif Thanks, but this is just a package. I need a way to open the native emoji keyboard.

Comment: Then you need to use native code for the time being. Follow these instructions:

 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44156657/10659482

Answer (score 0):

There's a new package called [keyboard_emoji_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_emoji_picker), and this package supports opening the native emoji keyboard.

[The instruction page for the package](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_emoji_picker) says we just have to put a `KeyboardEmojiPickerWrapper` in the widget tree, check if the native emoji keyboard is available using `.checkHasEmojiKeyboard()`, then call `await KeyboardEmojiPicker().pickEmoji()` and get the emoji back. I tried it, and it works great for me!

Just fyi, the package currently works only on iOS, so I'm using [emoji_picker_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter) (Flutter side emoji picker) for Android.

Answer (score 0):

There are available plugins that you can use to get this functionality, try exploring the [emoji_picker_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter).

> ###### Key features
>
> - Lightweight Package
> - Faster Loading
> - Null-safety
> - Completely customizable
> - Material Design and Cupertino mode
> - Emojis that cannot be displayed are filtered out (Android Only)
> - Optional recently used emoji tab
> - Skin Tone Support
> - Custom-Font Support

Tested it both on android and  iOS and seems pretty working well.

iOS

[image]

Android

[image]